# Django Admin Links Disabled on Heroku

Tags: django, heroku

I had an issue today where I deployed a small Django 1.5.1 app to Heroku. Everything was working fine except the admin. The links to my own app's models showed up, but were disabled.The weirdest part was on my local machine it worked fine, even when set in production mode and using foreman (which Heroku suggests).

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out I had to move these lines:

```
admin.site.register(Passage, PassageAdmin)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

Out of my models.py file and into a separate admin.py file. I've switched between both styles on previous Django apps and never had a problem. So I don't know if this is Heroku-specific or not.

Hopefully this helps someone else who might have the same strange issue!