# Django admin - disabled app links

Tags: django, django-admin

As you can see from the screenshot below, 'Invite' app link is disabled. Actually this is just a text. If I open the model directly - /admin/invite/invite/ - I get 404 page.

What is the reason for that? That looks really strange, never seen that before.

Django 1.5.1

Worth mentioning - we don't use any special HTML admin templates.

[image: screen]

Comment: Look at this answer: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16869487/1234326)
Maybe this will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out it was because we've extended urls in admin.py file. That was the reason.